# Multiple choice substitute?

Tags: substitute, user-input

Normally, a substitute with the `c` option gives me two options: (y)es or (n)o. Is it possible to have several numbered yes options to choose from?

**Example**

**File**

```
person: Alice
dog: Tobby
person: Bob
```

**Pattern 1** `:%s/person:/woman:/c`

**Pattern 2** `:%s/person:/man:/c`

Pattern 1 and 2 have the same search pattern but different replacement patterns. I want to unify them into one pattern with the option of pressing (1) for replacement 1, (2) for replacement 2 or (n) for no replacement.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The implementation of `:s//c` is fixed; what you're looking for is replacement with a Vimscript expression (`:help sub-replace-expr`). You can query a single-digit via `getchar()`, or prompt for longer numbers via `input()`:

```
:%s/person:/\=get(['woman', 'man'], getchar() - char2nr(1), submatch(0)) . ':'/
:%s/person:/\=get(['woman', 'man'], input('Your choice: ') - 1, submatch(0)) . ':'/
```

You can enter a higher number (`3` in your example) to perform no replacement.

---

If you need this often, it would make sense to define a custom `Query()` function for that. In there, you could also add a `:redraw`, so that you see the replacements that have already happened.

Comment: The command seems problematic. Only after I add the check command it works: `:%s/person:/\=get(['woman', 'man'], input('Your choice: ') - 1, submatch(0)) . ':'/c`

Comment: But add the `c` command will result in I need two steps to replace a string, which I think is needless.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the upvotes to my original question! I've now incorporated a `:SubstituteChoices` command into my [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602), which provides a robust implementation. The example in the question would be solved via:

```
:%SubstituteChoices/person:/woman:/man:/
```